# SQL query using data from other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a normalized table:

```
`Table: TheMovies`
id      | MovieName 
---------------------
1       | Zootopia 
2       | Moana 
3       | Toy Story

`Table: TheGenres`
id      | GenreName 
---------------------
21      | Action 
22      | Animation 
23      | Adventure

`Table: mMoviesGenres`
movieID | genreID 
---------------------
1       | 21 
1       | 23 
2       | 22
2       | 23 
2       | 21 
3       | 23
```

All works fine, but I need a Query which will shoe me similiar movies based on at least one of the genres of MovieID = 1.

Can you give me an sql query so I have a basic idea of doing that, to be able to create more advanced queries?

Comment: Come on. Try something.

Comment: @MrLister one movie can have more than one genre, as in the table provided by me

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you either show what output you want or explain clearly what is your goal?

Comment: You are going to have problems when you get two movies of the same name. Adding a column for year released could be enough. But in this day and age, does your database exist in isolation to the rest of the world? I suggest you take a look at [EIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIDR): "the Entertainment Identifier Registry, is a global unique identifier system for a broad array of audio visual objects, including motion pictures, television, and radio programs..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query using data from another table, you can join two or more tables into a single table by using JOIN clause.

```
SELECT TheMovies.* FROM mMoviesGenres JOIN TheMovies ON mMoviesGenres.MovieID = TheMovies.MovieID WHERE mMoviesGenres.MovieId <> 1 AND mMoviesGenres.GenreID IN (SELECT GenreID FROM mMoviesGenres WHERE MovieID = 1)
```

Learn more about join: [Using Join to Retrieve Data from Multiple Tables](http://mysqlcommands.com/mysql-commands-using-join-to-retrieve-data-from-multiple-tables/)

Comment: This worked for me, what about if I want that all genres to be same to be similiar?

Comment: You can try to add WHERE condition

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am new in mysql  :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TheMovies.*
FROM mMoviesGenres
JOIN TheMovies
  ON mMoviesGenres.MovieID = TheMovies.MovieID
WHERE
  mMoviesGenres.MovieId <> 1
  AND mMoviesGenres.GenreID IN (SELECT GenreID FROM mMoviesGenres WHERE MovieID = 1)
```

Comment: This does not work for me, it just shows me all movies.

Comment: @PHPLover: With the data you provided, that is the expected outcome. movie #1 has genres #21 and #23. You wanted all movies that share at least one genre with movie #1. Movie #2 shares genres #21 and #23 and movie #3 shares genre #23.

Comment: @JiriHrazdil : may be the output needs one one movie name to be shown.

Comment: @PHPLover : If above scenario is the intended output, in that case using a `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query will help solving your purpose. But it will be the showing the Movie Name based on Ascending order of the movieId. Hope it helps.